# PHP video upload

Tags: php, video

In my project, user will upload videos. So i have done simple code to check video file extension and moved to a particular folder. now problem is that only registered user can see that video. So i decided to check session while loading page which contain player to play video. but in view-source option , video file url available. so then can see that video using that url. now i need to check session before accessing that video folder. or is it possible to store video files in DB?
thanks in advance..

Comment: How about using a file-reading php file for accessing the videos and putting the videos in another directory that can't be accessed directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is insane, you need to make a rewrite or something like this video.php?id=blablabla, a then check if user is logged in, if he is, play (readfile) video. What type of file is it?

```
$id = $_GET["id"];

if($session == true)
{
  header("Content-type: video/flv");
  readfile("my/secret/path/".$id);
}
```

Comment: i hope i got solution. Thanks Webarto :-)

Comment: Use somekind of hash like /video/cafed00d, then query your database where you would store real filename, and play count, if user is logged in, increment play count, and readfile ;)

Answer (score 1):

everything that's shown for a user can always be copied and spread, but one way to prevent it from a more regular user would be using a php that reads an id/hash(basicaly a key of some sort) that is related to an video and then loads the video through file_read and outputs it.

store key and then the real url in a database then query the id to get the real url and then use a file reading function for example to stream it
the function could be [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fgets](http://php.net/fgets) or something similiar

Comment: I think it i'll be helpful.. I'll try and post comment here. thanks @Breezer.